# Поиск бинов в jar файлах

Tags: java, jsf

У меня есть jsf проект из которого я хочу вынести общую функциональность в отдельный модуль. Для этого был образован второй проект-ядро.

Если выносить туда бины при попытке обращения к ним получаем `ClassNotFound`.

Вроде бы достаточно расположить в `jar` файл `faces-config.xml`.
Есть подозрение что я его не туда положил. Структура проектов на скрине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что неправильно?